# sublime location of packages (can only find hex packages), how to modify packages?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I would like to add to a sublime package so that it can work right now (and then make a PR to the repo after).

I've installed `Expand Selection To Quotes` on `Sublime Text 3`. I go to `Preferences\Browse Packages` which takes me to `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages`

I cannot find this package anywhere, so I look around the App's root and found it here: `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/Installed Packages/Expand Selection to Quotes.sublime-package`

This file is filled with hex values and is `2.2KB` in size. I cannot modify this file and I'm not sure if it's the right file or if it's just a metadata file.

Comment: Short version: Packages can be `unpacked` (i.e. folders in the `Package` folder) or `packed` (i.e. `sublime-package` files). PackageControl installed packed packages unless the package author specifically tells it not to. `sublime-package` files are just zip files with a different extension so rename it to a `.zip` if you want to look inside.

Comment: Ah I didn't know that, tried to look for some information about it. I ended up forking the repo and just cloning it into the `Packages` folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with a different solution than to modify the existing folder.

I forked the repo, made my code updates, then cloned it into the `Packages` folder. Sublime picks it up automatically plus any further code changes that you want to tweak.